# Unable to run mocha test locally with firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, webpack, mocha.js

I am working on a react based frontend app that I am unit testing using mocha / enzyme.

The stack includes webpack, react, mocha + enzyme for testing, and firebase for auth / db / etc.

When I try and run `npm test` I get the following error due to firebase:

```
WEBPACK  Compiled successfully in 3412ms

 MOCHA  Testing...

 RUNTIME EXCEPTION  Exception occurred while loading your tests

TypeError: Cannot read property 'stringify' of undefined
    at Module.eval (webpack:///./node_modules/@firebase/webchannel-wrapper/dist/index.esm.js?:31:308)
    at eval (webpack:///./node_modules/@firebase/webchannel-wrapper/dist/index.esm.js?:136:30)
    ...

npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

What could be causing this error? This didn't happen before I imported firebase. Is there a webpack config I should tweak?

Comment: I have the same issue with vue + mocha-webpack.

Comment: Definitely let me know if you figure it out, it's driving me crazy.

Comment: Same issue here with vue + mocha + webpack, any news ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I've just figured this out. It seems to be an issue with how the tests are being loaded, causing the firebase package to be loaded in "web" mode even though the mocha test process is building in "node" mode... or something like that.

Anyways, here's the link that helped me solve this issue: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/1455#issuecomment-455712500.

Essentially, ignore node modules (specifically firebase) when bundling.